# Convergence/divergence of $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right) \cdot \sqrt{n^2+n+1} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I tried proving  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right) \cdot \sqrt{n^2+n+1}$$ diverges/converges with the comparison test but no matter what I can't prove it. 
I first tried with $\sin(x) < x$ and then $$\sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right) \cdot \sqrt{n^2+n+1} >  \sin \left(\frac{1}{n^2} \right) \cdot n$$ But with no end. Any hints/tips? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Jordan's Lemma we know $\sin(\theta)\geq \frac{2\theta}{\pi}$ for $\theta \in [0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. The lemma is easy to prove. Just note that $\sin(\theta)$ is concave on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and is greater then the straight line connecting the origin with $(x,\sin x)|_{x=\pi/2}=(\frac{\pi}{2},1)$.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin(\frac{1}{n^2}) \cdot \sqrt{n^2+n+1} \geq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\pi n^2}\sqrt{n^2}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\pi n}$$

The series diverges, because we found the harmonic series as lower bound.

Comment: I have just edited

Comment: We don't really need Jordan, just that $\sin x/x \to 1$ at $0.$

Answer (score 1):

It is well known that $$\sin\left(x\right)\sim x
 $$ as $x\rightarrow0
 $ so $$\sum_{n\geq1}\sin\left(\frac{1}{n^{2}}\right)\sqrt{n^{2}+n+1}\sim\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\sqrt{n^{2}+n+1}}{n^{2}}\sim\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n}$$ so it diverges.

Comment: we can not use this right?(i am a beginner, pls correct if i am wrong). Here $~$ means $<$ right. we can only decide convergence and not divergence. $f(n) < g(n)$, g(n) converges means f(n) converges and f(n) diverges means g(n) diverges. Pls clarify

Comment: @anirudhb $f(x) \sim g(x)$ means that $\frac{f(x)}{g(x)} \rightarrow 1$ when $x \rightarrow x_{0}$  where $x_{0} \in \mathbb{R} \cup \left\{ +\infty,-\infty\right\}  $. It doesn't mean that $f(x)<g(x).$

Comment: thanks! got it, can u pls suggest me 1 good book on real analysis??? these thoughts make things simple, lucid and beautiful

Comment: @anirudhb You can start with the classical "Principles of Mathematical Analysis" by Walter Rudin.